# React Hook, Array of objects from different call of Axios

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I got this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";

function InsideRacesComponent() {

    const route = "http://localhost:4000/api/standings";
    const [data, setData] = useState([{ raceName: "", raceCountryFlag: "" }]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(route).then(res => {

            //The arrays that I want to fetch data and combine
            const raceNameData = res.data[0].InsideRaceResults
            const raceCountryData = res.data[0].RaceResults

            
            raceNameData.forEach(races => {
                const raceName = races.gpId;
            });


            raceCountryData.forEach(races => {
                const flagLink = races.gpCountryImage;
            })
        })
    }, []);

    return (
      //some html
    )

}
```

If I log raceNameData it looks like this:

```
(17) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {_id: "5fe8c55830013624e4716eed", gpId: "Austrian Grand Prix", grandPrixDate: "Sunday, July 5", grandPrixTrack: "Red Bull Ring", RaceResult: Array(20)}
1: {_id: "5fe8c55830013624e4716f02", gpId: "Styrian Grand Prix", grandPrixDate: "Sunday, July 12", grandPrixTrack: "Red Bull Ring", RaceResult: Array(20)}
2: {_id: "5fe8c55830013624e4716f17", gpId: "Hungarian Grand Prix", grandPrixDate: "Sunday, July 19", grandPrixTrack: "Hungaroring", RaceResult: Array(20)}
...
```

And raceCountryData like this:

```
(17) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {_id: "5fe8c55830013624e4716edc", gpCountryName: "Austria", gpCountryImage: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thu…lag_of_Austria.svg/1200px-Flag_of_Austria.svg.png"}
1: {_id: "5fe8c55830013624e4716edd", gpCountryName: "Austria", gpCountryImage: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thu…lag_of_Austria.svg/1200px-Flag_of_Austria.svg.png"}
2: {_id: "5fe8c55830013624e4716ede", gpCountryName: "Hungary", gpCountryImage: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thu…lag_of_Hungary.svg/1920px-Flag_of_Hungary.svg.png"}
...
```

**Im looking for this when I log data from React Hook**

```
console.log("data: " + data);

// data: [{ raceName: "Austrian Grand Prix", raceCountryFlag: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thu…lag_of_Austria.svg/1200px-Flag_of_Austria.svg.png" }, { raceName: "Styrian Grand Prix", raceCountryFlag: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thu…lag_of_Austria.svg/1200px-Flag_of_Austria.svg.png" } , { raceName: "Hungarian Grand Prix", raceCountryFlag: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thu…lag_of_Hungary.svg/1920px-Flag_of_Hungary.svg.png" }, ...]
```

I've tried with this in each one of the "array.forEach":

```
setData(prevValue => [...prevValue, { raceName: raceName, raceCountryFlag: "" }]

//and

setData(prevValue => [...prevValue, { raceName: "", raceCountryFlag: flagLink }]
```

of course my aproach has not logic ...

Thanks!

Comment: You would need some common item in name raceNameData and raceCountryData data so you can link the two. Right now the closest link is the country name, however they are different ie "Austrian Grand Prix" and "Austria".

Comment: As @Akshay said, you need to have a relationship between `raceNameData` and `raceCountryData`. I assume that you're using MongoDB, so you're probably looking for something like [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/). And I advise you that you take care of that business logic on the back end, not the front end, if you're the one developing it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I needed to combine that arrays for just once because I was doing an "array.map()" in the return of the component, and I wanted to print not only the name of the GP but also wanted to add a image from the country. It's my first web proyect, but I think there should be no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed that `raceNameData` and `raceCountryData` array have same length. Used `Array.map` instead of `forEach`.

```js
const data = raceNameData.map((race, index) => ({
  raceName: race.gpId,
  raceCountryFlag: raceCountryData[index].gpCountryImage
}));
```